# Why the execution renders wrong output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def eoo(a):
  if a%2 == 0:
    print("Entered value is even")
  else:
    print("Entered value is odd")
b = 5556.4
print(b)
eoo(b)
```

The output is

```
5556.4
Entered value is odd
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: What did you expect `a%2` to do?

Comment: Check the value of `5556.4%2` and you'll see that it's not equal to zero.

Comment: `5556.4 % 2` is `0.4`. Categories such as "even" and "odd" do not really make all that much sense for decimal numbers. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)): "A formal definition of an even number is that it is an integer of the form n = 2k, where k is an integer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not wrong. `5556.4 % 2` is not zero, thus you get in the `else` case:

```
>>> 5556.4 % 2
0.3999999999996362
```

It's your assumption that any number that is not even must be odd that is wrong. In fact, categories such as "even" and "odd" do not make all that much sense for decimal numbers. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) (emphasis mine)

> Parity is a mathematical term that describes the property of an **integer**'s inclusion in one of two categories: even or odd. [...] A formal definition of an even number is that it is an **integer** of the form *n = 2k*, where *k* is an **integer**.

Instead, you could, e.g., change your method to something like this:

```
def eoo(a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        print("Entered value is even")
    elif a % 2 == 1:
        print("Entered value is odd")
    else:
        print("Entered value is neither even nor odd")
```

Or, if you are only interested in the integer part of the number, use `int(a) % 2`, or `round(a) % 2` to check whether the number rounded to the nearest integer is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

a%2 will give you the remainder when you divide a by 2.  when you divide 5556.4 by 2 your remainder is not 0, it is .4.  That is why you are going to your else condition.